# MAMP won't start MySql due to invalid port

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've broken my MAMP installation. In Preferences I mistakenly set the MySQL Port to '8888-8889'. Predicatably MySQL then wouldn't start.

Even now I've restored it to '8889' it still chokes trying to use the invalid value. I get the following in the mysql_error_log.err when I try and start it:

> 140528 14:15:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
>   140528 14:15:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
>   Unknown suffix '-' used for variable 'port' (value '8889-8889')
>   140528 14:15:31 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Error while setting value '8889-8889' to 'port'
>   140528 14:15:31 [ERROR] Aborting

Is there somewhere MAMP stores its Preferences that I can edit manually?

Comment: I'm sure the default MySQL port is 3306?

Comment: look for a file called `my.cnf` - try: "/etc/my.cnf" OR "/etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf" OR "~/.my.cnf"

Comment: Tried 3306 too. 8889 was what I was using prior to my breaking it. The only my.cnf files on my machine are unused, belong to macports and reference port 3306.

Comment: Seems I can start things from the command line okay - but would be nice to get the GUI working too.